# "No features were split:" error when using Split Features tool in QGIS

Tags: qgis, polygon, geometry, error, splitting

I want to split a fairly large polygon with the Split Features tool from the Advanced Digitizing Toolbar in QGIS. However, I get an error:

> No features were split: If there are selected features, the split tool
> only applies to those. If you would like to split all features under
> the split line, clear the selection.

I can confirm that no features are selected and that the polygon has a valid geometry. I am able to split smaller sections of the polygon (fewer nodes between splits) but not larger sections of the polygon.

Data sample available: http://www.filedropper.com/problempolygon
QGIS version: 3.18.1 (Windows)
CRS: EPSG:32718
Data source: Shapefile
Geom type: Multipolygon (Single parts)

Any suggestions on what the problem might be and how to fix it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For me your shapefile with polygons seems to be okay. I checked it with the ["Check validity"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeometry.html#check-validity).

Here is the recreated problem:
[image: problem]

It appeared because basic usage-requirements were not met when working with the ["Split Features"](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/editing_geometry_attributes.html#split-features).

So, there are several ideas on how to overcome it:

1. Either the splitting line has to be drown beyond the geometry
   [image: resolution_1]
2. or the splitting line has to snap vertices/segments of the geometry
   [image: resultion_2]

Comment: Solution 1 and 2 worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In case your feature consists of inner rings, make sure to use the "split feature" tool in such a way that it covers the entire feature.

For example:
[image: wrong use of split tool]

and in the right case below:
[image: right use of split tool]